# Junit tests are failing after moving from spring boot 2.5.* to 2.6.*

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-kafka

I am working on moving my kafa CDC application to spring boot 2.6.* . But when I upgrade to spring boot 2.6.*, Junit tests are failing with following error

```
CdcConsumerApplicationTest > testMainApplicationLoad() FAILED
      java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
          Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException at SpringBootCondition.java:60
              Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException at AnnotationParser.java:724
```

This is simple Junit example test that is failing

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AppTestConfiguration.class })
@EmbeddedKafka(partitions = 1, topics = { "XXX.SOME-DB2-CHANGE" })
public class CdcConsumerApplicationTest {

   

    @Test
    public void testMainApplicationLoad() {

    }
}
```

If I run this tests locally on my IDE, they works fine but they are failing when running via jenkins. All my Junits are junit 5. Anything I am missing or I need to change when moving from spring boot 2.5 to 2.6 and further ?

Comment: Please add the **full stacktrace** not a snippet... And did you only upgrade Spring Boot or did you change something else as well?

Comment: That is the only error I see on stacktrace and yes the only upgrade I did was upgraded from 2.5.14 to 2.6.0 .

Comment: I doubt it is all, there is at least more logging, this looks like the output of your test method **not your actual logfile**. Why 2.6.0 and not the latest in the 2.6.x branch. Make sure you aren't trying to outsmart the Spring dependency management.

Comment: i don't see any error and that is all i have.To your question on why 2.6.0, my app is currently using 2.4.*. I upgraded to 2.7.* and saw this error. I started moving down one version at a time and i found breaking happen when moving from 2.5 to 2.6. i am thinking this is dependency issues but could not figure out anything

Comment: Check the actual console output, there will be more output.

Comment: figured out what is causing this but not sure how to fix this. If i take out this dependency it works but not sure how can i make it work as i need this
`implementation (group: 'io.confluent', name: 'timestamp-interceptor', version: '7.1.2')`

Comment: Have you tried upgrading it to a more recent version?